# What is that inertia that makes the nose rise in a spin?

Tags: cessna-172, spins

The Flight Training manual mentions
For Ex. 13- spin, that the nose drops due to the loss of lift, and rises due to inertia forces.
Can someone explain to me that inertia force making the nose rise, like Im a 5 year old?

Answer (score 2):

The pitch-up moment comes from the lengthwise mass distribution: Since the airplane swings around a vertical axis, this movement creates an inertial force. For an observer who rotates with the aircraft, this is the centrifugal force of the masses, like in the picture below:

[image]

Mass forces in a spin (own work). $\omega_z$ is the rotational velocity around the spin axis, r is the radius between the spin axis and the local mass and m is the mass itself.

The rear parts have a longer radius and, therefore, cause a larger horizontal force at the same rotation speed than the more forward masses. Only if all masses have the same radius (almost possible in an unswept flying wing, or in a vertical dive) will the uprighting moment be zero.

Comment: You could say that it's a tilted gyro, spinning about an axis somewhere near or inboard of the main landing gear of the stalled side, and the tendency to spin flat is basically the gyro's erection force is stronger than the aerodynamic forces trying to keep it tilted.

Comment: @JohnK It is the usual tendency of a spinning body to change its axis of rotation to one perpendicular to its main inertial axes, as in [inertial coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertia_coupling). Which is the vertical axis for airplanes.

Comment: I own a Pazmany PL-2. The Taiwanese built 50 or so of them as a cadet trainer. They discovered they spun flat after about 6 turns. They started a spin test program, doing 300 plus spins on an a/c with a spin chute, trying every bandaid they could think of, strakes, dorsal fins, etc. They thought maybe the tip tanks were doing it, but removing them didn't help. Nothing worked and they gave up.

Comment: @JohnK For flat spins the shape of the fuselage nose is the most influential part. It should be flat (see [F-5 shark nose](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19790001876/downloads/19790001876.pdf)). Grob made similar experiences with their G-110 which had a very stable flat spin. The G-115 had a changed fin to cure it from flat spinning.